# SQLite basic JOIN

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Let's say I have 3 tables:

- shop
- address (related to shop by a nullable one-to one)
- photo (related to shop by a nullable many-to one)

How can I write the raw SQLite in order to retrieve all shops in all the cases (but with the address if exists and all photos if exists)?

```
SELECT * FROM shop LEFT JOIN address ON address.idShop = shop.id
LEFT JOIN photo ON photo = shop.id
```

This only gives me the matching results (so if I have the matching address and the matching photo).

Comment: You can use left join on tables with unique key available in both tables

Comment: Why the -1 for the question ?

Comment: Txs bindal I've tried with left join but I was able to retrieve only the values matching with the unique key...

Comment: pskin I ve edited my question please remove your -1 sorry. I didnt post my request as I know is incomplete... Ts for help ! :)

Comment: try some examples from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm) (it is not my -1)

Comment: I have already seen this page I didnt found the answer.

Comment: Show some example data and the desired result.

Comment: Rotwang I can show all the effort that you need. Dont hesitate to ask me for more efforts.

Comment: So adding LEFT OUTER JOIN seems to do the trick but I get now one entry by "photo" (I have a shop by photo so duplicate shop for different photos).

Sorry if some people misenterstood my lack of knowledge with a lack of effort. For the others txs for help. In other words how to do a one to many relation query...

Comment: simply post you data and the desired result, like [this](http://ideone.com/771iMR)

Comment: Txs pskink. I don't even know what I m supposed to have in pure sqlite... I ussually use ORM. 
The goal is to have a list of shops (which contains an address object and a list of photo in each shop...)

Comment: so did you try this ideone link i posted?

Comment: Yes and it works partially with the LEFT OUTER JOIN as I said before. But I'm getting duplicate shops for each photo. Is there a way to have only one shop and several photos by shop ?

Comment: @Hiromi With pure SQL that's all you'll get: it only returns rows, so to return one-row-per-photo (which is what you want) it needs to repeat the address/shop details in each row. You have to take that result, and build your own nested objects (new shop whenever the ID changes; new photo added to current shop's "photo bucket" when the ID is the same) -- or use another layer that does it for you.

Comment: Finaly an answer. Txs @TripeHound !